# How does this Turnkey Linux domain-controller replace Microsoft Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, samba4, webmin, turnkey

How does [this VM](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller) replace Microsoft Active Directory, on a network with Windows Machines on it?  Is there a specific component that is installed that replaces it?  Is it Samba or Webmin?  Are there any limitations in comparison to actual Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Domain Controller container from Turnkey uses Samba, and includes the web-based interface (webmin).

Samba is the component that replaces AD.

It's difficult to say whether there are limitations compared to Microsoft AD; it depends on what components you are using from Microsoft. Generally speaking: no, there is no limitation, and in fact you might find SAMBA far more liberating, since it's a more flexible system than Microsoft's implementation. But obviously, it does depend on what you are used to, what you are expecting, and so on. Given that Turnkey is $0 to try, a trial run is probably the best determining factor.

Comment: I've been wanting to learn a bit more windows stuff without shelling out $$$ for Windows Server.  The prospect looks interesting.  I've used Samba in the past, but only for file sharing between Linux and Windows machines.